# ColorBox's slideshow turns off after closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I want to use ColorBox for my site. I used this code:

```
$('a.gal').each(function() {
    $(this).colorbox({
        rel:'g',
        slideshow: true,
        scrolling: false,
        slideshowAuto: false,
        returnFocus: false
    });
});
```

And my problem is - when I first click on an image, slideshow works. But when I close it and then reopen it, the slideshow button is missing. What might cause this?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37365/

Comment: Link to the test site?

Comment: Sorry, it's for my client and it's wip now. Problem is - I made jsfiddle with it and there it works good.

Comment: Could you include the jsfiddle link, please.

Comment: I've put it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I've figured what the problem is. It's something to do with **placehold.it** images. When I load the images locally or from a different URL the slideshow is working just fine.

```
<a href="your_image_location" class="gal"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x150.jpg" class="attachment-full">
```

jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/mmetsalu/QKUJZ/2/)

If it's still not working for you, check inside the `head` tags to see if you've included all the necessary scripts:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: No, images used at my site wasn't from placehold.it, but from my local server.

Comment: I'd like to see what you have between the `head` tags. Also have a look at my fiddle and tell me if it's working on your end?